# Accessing the entire source code of a function that has "useMethod("packagefunction") in Rstudio?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to extend the functionality of a package and therefore trying to access the entire code behind one of the functions.

The package in question is RQuantLib and I am trying to see the entire code used in the function "DiscountCurve"

The result I get is simply:

```
function (params, tsQuotes, times = seq(0, 10, 0.1), legparams = list(dayCounter = "Thirty360", 
  fixFreq = "Annual", floatFreq = "Semiannual")) 
{
  UseMethod("DiscountCurve")
}
```

I have tried quite a few solutions as posted in this thread with no luck: [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

UseMethod("DiscountCurve") does not tell me much. As far as I understand this is a translated package from C++.
I am rather new to coding so it is possible that I have just not implemented the correct solution in the thread above correctly.

Edit for more detial on methods used so far:
Results from methods:
> methods("DiscountCurve")
[1](http://prnt.sc/tws9rq) DiscountCurve.default*

When checking methods(Class="default") I get 184 results. Due to space I will post screenshots of the code: [prnt.sc/tws98x](http://prnt.sc/tws98x)

Further using getAnywhere: [prnt.sc/tws9rq](http://prnt.sc/tws9rq)

Comment: please tell us a little more about the solutions you've tried. I would expect you to have gotten somewhere with `methods()` and `getAnywhere()` from the accepted answer ... can you edit your question to include the results of following these steps? (Just running `methods()` won't get you anywhere, you have to follow the steps from the linked answer ...)

Comment: Here are the results

    > methods("DiscountCurve")
    [1] DiscountCurve.default*

When checking methods(Class="default") I get 184 results. Due to space I will post screenshots of the code: 
https://prnt.sc/tws98x

Further using getAnywhere:
https://prnt.sc/tws9rq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do:

```r
RQuantLib:::DiscountCurve.default
```

You will see the actual code that runs when the generic calls `UseMethod("DiscountCurve")` . However, you are likely to be disappointed, because essentially that function is a glorified type-checker which passes your parameters safely to another unexported function called `discountCurveEngine`, which looks like this:

```r
RQuantLib:::discountCurveEngine
function (rparams, tslist, times, legParams) 
{
    .Call(`_RQuantLib_discountCurveEngine`, rparams, tslist, 
        times, legParams)
}
```

Which, you will see, is actually a thin wrapper for the C++ code that actually does the calculation. It is written in Rcpp-flavoured C++ and you can read the source code [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/src/discount.cpp#L26). However, this in turn calls functions from another C++ library called Quantlib.

Depending on how keen you are, and how proficient you are in C++, you may find this enjoyably challenging or dishearteningly baffling, but at least you know where to find the source code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not coded in C++ at all so I guess it will be a challenge, but this is a big step forwards after a long time being stuck so that is great. Very quick and thorough reply as well so thank you for that @Allan Cameron

Comment: You're welcome @Qfin . From reviewing the code, this is very nicely written C++ and because it uses Rcpp, you should get a good idea of what it is doing. Good luck!